# AVAssetWriter Fails at iPhone X Resolution w/ h.264 but NOT w/ h.265

Tags: ios, avfoundation, h.264, avassetwriter, hevc

I'm using an AVAssetWriter to write realtime video, appending the stream of `CMSampleBufferRef`s.

One of my chosen output resolutions is 1376 x 2436 (for the iPhone X, adding some width so it meets a 1.77 aspect ratio).

Weird thing is... when I output it as HEVC, everything is great. But if I elect for h.264 (as only iPhone 7 onward can produce HEVC, yet someone on an iPhone 5s could be talking to someone on an iPhone X), the write fails.

```
Error Domain = AVFoundationErrorDomain 
Code = -11800 
"The operation could not be completed" 
UserInfo = {
   NSLocalizedFailureReason = An unknown error occurred (-12902), 
   NSLocalizedDescription = The operation could not be completed, 
   NSUnderlyingError = 0x1c424b550 {
      Error Domain = NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12902 "(null)"
   }
 }
```

the h.264 settings work for all other output resolutions: 640x1136, 750x1334 and 1080x1920

h.264 output settings:

```
@{   AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecH264,
     AVVideoWidthKey:@(mediaSize.width),
     AVVideoHeightKey:@(mediaSize.height),
     AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey:@{
                        AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: @4500000,
                        AVVideoAllowFrameReorderingKey:@NO,
                        AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264High41,
                        AVVideoH264EntropyModeKey:AVVideoH264EntropyModeCABAC,
                        AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey: @(30)
                        }
     };
```

hevc output settings:

```
@{ AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecTypeHEVC,
   AVVideoWidthKey:@(mediaSize.width),
   AVVideoHeightKey:@(mediaSize.height),
   AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey:@{
        AVVideoProfileLevelKey : (__bridge NSString *)kVTProfileLevel_HEVC_Main_AutoLevel,
        AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: @4500000,
        AVVideoAllowFrameReorderingKey:@NO,
        AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey: @(30)
        }
};
```